# How can we Delete All domain cookies in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

My requirement is Delete all cookies (All Domain) cookies using Selenium WebDriver. But in selenium we are able to delete only domain cookies. So i'm trying to use keypress events that is Ctrl+Shift+Delete.

Here I tried like below. `Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
        action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys(Keys.DELETE).perform();`
but it is not showing any browser alert?

Can any one please assist me in this case? or any alternative solution to delete all domain cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below java code to delete cookies.

```
protected void deleteCookie(String cookieName)
{
String cookieDomain =
CTPropertiesManager.getProperty("site.properties","site.cookie.domain");

try
{
//get all cookies
Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();

Cookie ctCookie=null;
if (cookies !=null)
{
for(int i=0; i<cookies.length; i++)
{
ctCookie=cookies[i];
if (ctCookie.getName().trim().equals(cookieName))
{
if ( cookieDomain != null )
{
ctCookie.setDomain(cookieDomain);
}

ctCookie.setPath("/ct");
ctCookie.setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(ctCookie);
}
}//end for
}//end if cookie
}//end try
catch(Exception e){
CTLogManager.log(e);
}
}//end deleteCookie()
```